# Common login between joomla and another php website

Tags: php, joomla1.5

I am learning joomla and I have question regarding it.
I develop a website in php say **www.xyz.com/php_website/** and Its CMS is created in Joomla say **www.xyz.com/joomla_website/** it means both are in same server but both have different login system. so I want to do is if admin login in php_website,he can also logged in automatically in joomla_website,basically I want a common login between these websites.....Please anybody can give me a solution for my problem....Thanks in advace.

Comment: joomla stores user data in specific variables and format in `SESSION` files. so when you login on your `website`, it creates his own session (or cookies - we dont know what CMS it is). so main problem - make this data format and storage - common. thats means that you need to **rewrite** your login function and other userinfo storing structure. thats a huge piece of work here.

Comment: Use a [single sign on](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on) solution.